# SQL Server restore operation reliability

Tags: sql-server, backup-restoration

I have a simple backup scheme on my SQL Server 2008 R2 that performs a weekly full backup and a daily incremental backup. Backups are retained for two weeks and everything works fine albeit there are two small issues:

1) After the second full backup, the previous week of incremental backups disapears from the restore backup window on Sql server management studio. Why does this happen? I can restore the backups fine from files, but I would rather prefer that the entire backup list from a specific database to be present on said dialog box, which would simplfy the restore operation for the user (picking checkboxes instead of selecting files with similar names).

2) I also noticed a very worrisome behaviour on that "Restore database" window. Say you want to restore database X. As customary, you'd restore it to temp-x (ie. to another database instead of overwriting the original one). But to my surprise the DEFAULT target MDF and LDF files of the restore would be the ones being used by the original DB. (ie. X.MDF and X_0.ldf or similar). If a user forgets to check that second tab with the default files, disaster ensues. How can this be averted ? Note that the "overwrite existing database" option was unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the incremental backups to be retained, the second and subsequent full backups need to be "copy-only" backups, so that the full backup does not break/reset the chain.

The solution for #2 requires a competent administrator.